# The button size in the simulation is very different from in the storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, size

Like the title says, I cannot get the size of one of my buttons to match that in the storyboard. When I run my program, the button shows up much bigger, taking up a large portion of the screen, which the others don't do. I will include screenshots to show what I mean. I am having trouble finding out how to fix this. I've already tried Clean.

[A screenshot of the storyboard, then quiz when it is run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZQX1.jpg)

Comment: welcome to the world of `auto layout` and `size classes`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use constraints to make you button or whatever controls looks like what you want on different screens and devices. You should use your storyboard file to put your constraints.

So your button should in the simplest form should be looking in the storyboard file like:

[image]

So be sure that all your constraints are blue (blue lines on the screen). They can be orange as well but it is the signal that something can go wrong when you run your project with position or size of your button.

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I was missing.